# Python: Why is this regular expression not working?

Tags: python, regex

So I have this regex working as expected on pythex.org but it refuses to work in pycharm.

```
somepath = 'C:\Work_stuff\common\something\anything\cool_stuff' 
path_without_common = re.sub('.*\\common\\', "", somepath)
```

Comment: you're missing quotes around `somepath`

Comment: my mistake, but its fine in the code :)

Comment: [Edit] your question to show the *exact* code you're running as well as the outputs/error and the desired output.

Comment: Quotes fixed. ERROR =     raise source.error("bad escape %s" % escape, len(escape))
sre_constants.error: bad escape \c at position 2

Comment: Probably not working because somepath is not r"somepath" so the "\" are escaping characters

Comment: try making `some_path` a raw string: `somepath = r'C:\Work_stuff\common\something\anything\cool_stuff'`

Comment: expected output @EDU?

Comment: I already VTC'd as no [mcve] but this is a dupe. Here's one candidate: [regex sub is throwing some error in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29482541/regex-sub-is-throwing-some-error-in-python)

Comment: Note  that `'\\'` is a single backslash, and you need two to match a backlash with a regex. So, you need `'aaa\\\\bbb'` or `r'aaa\\bbb'`. See [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/LbH7Mb).

Comment: Thx Ryan and Pault. Didnt know about that raw thingy. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Bad escape.

This is an example working:

```
somepath = r'C:\Work_stuff\common\something\anything\cool_stuff'
path_without_common = re.sub(r"\\common", "", somepath)
```